# In Open Graph markup, what's the use of 'og:locale:alternate' without the location (href)?

Tags: html, markup, facebook-opengraph

Facebook's Open Graph Protocol markup [allows for defining](http://ogp.me/#optional) the current web page's locale, and any alternative locales it's also available in, using a markup like this:

```
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_GB">
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR">
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES">
```

The current page's permalink can be easily deduced (from the URL, Canonical URL meta tag, or `og:url`).

But what's the point of including `og:locale:alternate` without their respective URLs? How is it at all useful?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's clearly stated in the article titled "[Internationalizing Open Graph Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/11/11/605/)" on the official Facebook Developers blog:

> ### Translating Objects
>
> In order to translate Open Graph objects, two things must happen. The
> developer must specify which locales are supported by the object
> through Open Graph meta tags, and the app must return the correct
> strings in the requested locale. For example, if the object can be
> translated into French and Spanish, the markup that describes this
> would look like the following:
>
> ```
> <html>
> <head>
>     <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="fr_FR" />
>     <meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="es_ES" />
>     ...
> </head>
>     ...
> </html>
> ```
>
> When Facebook needs to render an object in one of the specified
> locales, we will make a request to the object URL with the `fb_locale`
> URL parameter set, e.g. `&fb_locale=es_ES`. The app should then return
> the object markup in that specified locale. For more details on
> translating Open Graph objects, please look at the [Open Graph I18N
> doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/).
>
> You can debug issues with translating objects by adding a `fb_locale`
> parameter, e.g. `fb_locale=es_ES`, to the [Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug?fb_locale=es_ES) and entering
> your object URL. If you change or add locales for a particular object,
> you can make Facebook re-scrape your object to pick up the changes by
> adding a `scrape=true` as described in the [Objects section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects/) in the
> I18N documentation.